# Reading a file path in a bash commad

Tags: java, bash, path

I have this script:

```
#! /bin/bash -

# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

JDK_PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java"
WEKA="C:\Program Files\Weka\weka-3-4\weka.jar"

# ----------------------------------

COMMONS_CLI=./lib/commons-cli-1.0.jar
MRC=./lib/jmrc.jar

LIBS=.:$WEKA:$COMMONS_CLI:$MRC:bin/

$JDK_PATH -Xmx512m -classpath $LIBS recognizer.PersonalityRecognizer $*
```

From [this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD) project

And I try to run this command in git bash command line

```
./PersonalityRecognizer -i ../output_dir -d -t 2 -a ../mairesse_Apache.arff
```

However I receive this error:

```
$ ./PersonalityRecognizer -i ../output_dir -d -t 2 -a ../mairesse_Apache.arff
./PersonalityRecognizer: line 15: C:\Program: No such file or directory
```

Is there any problem with the space character in Java path? How can I write it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
"$JDK_PATH" -Xmx512m -classpath "$LIBS" recognizer.PersonalityRecognizer $*
```

ot bash will see spaces as separators not as part of the path

Comment: Thank you it works. Java executed fine but for weka I receive this error `C:/weka/weka.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
C:/weka/weka.jar: line 2: $'\270\260^?': command not found
C:/weka/weka.jar: line 3:▒▒^?▒▒+▒}▒META-INF/MANIFEST.MFMʱ: No such file or directory
C:/weka/weka.jar: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
C:/weka/weka.jar: line 4: `▒0▒▒=▒w▒Q▒▒▒J▒▒A:d]▒gDr)ҷ▒n▒▒▒{▒▒▒R̙▒▒k▒Xi▒▒?i▒▒
                                                                          ▒▒q▒V+` any idea for this?